# Connecting JSON+LD and Microdata by id

Tags: html, data-structures, microdata, json-ld

I am looking for a way to merge my pre-defined LD+JSON with microdata defined on the html as properties. Do you see ANY way of achieving this?

I searched a while now and cannot find the answer to my question. I even don't know, if there is an answer to that ;)

Tried a lot with itemref, itemid, @id.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Article",
    "@id": "a"
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <article itemid="a" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <h1 itemprop="headline">Foobar</h1>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not possible. Think of it this way: two separate languages that do not have a common interface for exchanging data. One way of managing consistency (coordinating data) is to inject source data into the separate structures. Mustache or handlebars could do the work. But you'll have to load the appropriate JS lib, and then add the delimiters to your HTML.

Comment: Makes sense to me on first thought. Had hope that there would still be a way